# Animation on Xcode 7 on my view controller would only work if i set the view controller as initial view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

i was making the animation for my app, but if the view controller which i am working my animations on is not set to initial view controller then the animation would not work. I wont to access this view controller by pressing a button on the view controller before. The animations on the first view controller (initial view controller) work but not on any other view controllers. Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the solution. To fix it i needed to add a navigation controller in the beginning, and to make it disappear when i review my app i type

self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true

now i have another question, how can i hide the navigation controller from the storyboard when i edit the view controller, because it is getting in the way and messing my auto layout constraints. Thanks

Comment: Ask an another question for this. And please, search before ask.